# electron remote global value undefined

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using `var remote = require('electron').remote;` and trying to get the value using `remote.getGlobal('config').siteUrl`

In my main.js I am setting the value using `global`.

`global.config = {siteUrl:"https://localhost:8088"};`

on the html side (renderer side) I am getting the value as `undefined` while creating the darwin `.app` on mac.

On the other when I run the app using `npm start` it works fine.

Comment: `{   {} "main":"your_electron_config.js",{}  }` Check your package.json file for your Main script looks the elctron config